# Дано целое число A и натуральное число i. Выведите число, которое получается из числа A установкой значения i-го бита = 1

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

```
int a,b=1,i; 
cin>>a; 
cin>>i; 
b<<=i; 
a = a^b; 
cout<<a; 
return 0;
```

правильно ли составлена программа ?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, вы *изменяете* значение бита.

Чтобы его установить -

```
a |= (1 << i);
```

Ну и неплохо бы проверять значения - того же `i` - укладывается ли оно в диапазон; значение же `a`, как и `b`, должно быть беззнаковым, иначе могут теоретически быть всякие тонкости :)